# Mount Windows share on linux host preserving ACLs

Tags: linux, windows, domain, samba

I have a debian server with some samba shares. It is joined to a Windows domain (Win 2008 R2) and the users are mapped using winbindd. Is it possible to mount a remote Windows share (situated on win7) to copy the files/directories preserving ACLs?

Comment: There is (in reality) no linux filesystem that supports ACLs. So, no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically. But the configuration requirements are [quite specific](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs) so unless you set up the existing shares with this in mind, the chances are astronomically small that your current file system supports ACL's.

(The other answer by @Marco is wrong; it assumes Linux *only* supports ancient UNIX protection bits. And the SSH bit is really weird; SSH is entirely unrelated to SMB)